# Not able to attach multiple listeners with Nodejs EventEmitter objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run following code

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    let stream = fs.createReadStream('io.txt');  

    stream.on('readable', function () {
        console.log("readable");
        stream.on('data',function (chunk) {
            console.log("Hello world!");
        });
    });
```

I get this:

```
readable
Hello world!
readable
```

`readable` event's callback is fired twice, once when the file is readable and once before `end` event. This is as mentioned in the docs.

However, if I do this:

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    let stream = fs.createReadStream('io.txt');

    stream.on('readable', function () {
        console.log("readable");
        stream.on('data',function (chunk) {
            console.log("Hello world!");
        });
    });

//added the following
    for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
        stream.on('data',function (chunk) {
            console.log('HELLO WORLD'+i);;
        });
    }
```

The output is:

```
HELLO WORLD0
HELLO WORLD1
HELLO WORLD2
readable
```

Here readable is just fired once which I presume is before the `end` event. Why this difference? Am I doing some stupid mistake?

Comment: I think the problem in nested subscription to events. from documentation: In some cases, attaching a listener for the 'readable' event will cause some amount of data to be read into an internal buffer.